# Compare Datatable with C# List

Tags: c#, datatable, compare

I am working on a MVC project in which i am Stuck with code where i have to compare DataTable value with C# List and Save list value in Sql Database below is my code :

```
private void AddNumbers(DataTable dTable)
{
    List<NumberRates> aPriceList = new List<NumberRates>();
    NumberRates priceobj = null;

    using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument(filePath, "Pdf RATES"))
    {
        SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();

        for (int row = 11; row <= stats.EndRowIndex; ++row)
        {
            try
            {
                priceobj = new NumberRates();

                priceobj.destination = sl.GetCellValueAsString(row, 1);

                priceobj.a_price = sl.GetCellValueAsDecimal(row, 3);

                aPriceList.Add(priceobj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dTable columns contains name , description And Number

Now i want to compare List values with DataTable columns and
 if list.destination==dTable.description then list.destinatiom = dTble.Number .

Hope I am able to explain my problem .

Comment: Your last statement is confusing. You want to set **list.destination** with dTble.Number? Then the comparison makes little sense. Please show the definition of the class NumberRates

Answer (score 0):

You just need a loop over the NumberRates list and for each element check if the passed table contains the Destination key. If you find it then just copy the Number value to the appropriate property of the NumberRates class.

```
foreach(NumberRates element in aPriceList)
{
    DataRow[] match = dTable.Select("Description = '" + element.destination + "'");
    if(match.Length > 0)
        element.Number = match[0].Number;
}
```

or better, to avoid a second loop just add the above logic to your current code

```
for (int row = 11; row <= stats.EndRowIndex; ++row)
{
    try
    {
        priceobj = new NumberRates();

        priceobj.destination = sl.GetCellValueAsString(row, 1);

        priceobj.a_price = sl.GetCellValueAsDecimal(row, 3);

        aPriceList.Add(priceobj);

        DataRow[] match = dTable.Select("Description = '" + priceobj.destination + "'");
        if(match.Length > 0)
           priceobj.Number = match[0].Number;
    }

}
```

Note, the above code assumes that there is a one-to-one relationship between destination and description. If you have more than one record in your datatable that matches the Description search then you have to specify what you want to do with the values in the other records retrieved by the Select method.